# How do I create a custom UINavigationBar with the bottom two corners rounded?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I've gotten the navigation bar to round only the bottom two corners but when I use clipsToBounds = true, it clips the top of the navigation bar as well. In the image below, I want the entire bar to be orange but only a portion of it is orange.

[image: navBar]

```
import UIKit

class MyNavBar: UINavigationBar {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupNavBar()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupNavBar()
}

func setupNavBar() {
    tintColor = .white
    barTintColor = .orange
    layer.cornerRadius = 20
    layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the `UINavigationBar` view hierarchy or alter layer properties. there is a dedicated method `setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)` to customize `UINavigationBar` appearance. I'd suggest checking **Customizing the Appearance of a Navigation Bar** in [Apple's UIKit Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar) .

> To allow complete customization over the appearance of navigation bars, you can additionally provide custom background and shadow images. To provide a custom background image, use the `setBackgroundImage(_:for:barMetrics:)` method, providing a `UIImage` object for the appropriate bar position and metrics values.

Comment: Last thing I would add for anyone seeing this; set ```shadowImage = UIImage()``` to remove the random border shadow that sits below the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can Add this navBar as custom view in your controller to get the same look and feel

```
class CustomNavBar: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setupview()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setupview()
}

func setupview() {
    tintColor = .white
    backgroundColor = .orange
    layer.cornerRadius = 20
    layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    clipsToBounds = true
  }
}
```

And i you controller baseClass

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    let nav = CustomNavBar()
    self.view.addSubview(nav)

   nav.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nav.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    nav.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    nav.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX).isActive = true
    nav.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out but the interaction between the custom UIView at the top and the UINavigationBar doesn't work very well. Even when I try to set the background and barTintColor on the UINavigationBar to clear, transparent, or with an alpha of 0 it seems to have some default styling that it sticks on there.