# How do you round bottom corners of UINavigation bar with a search bar using large titles

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationbar

When attempting to crate a UINavigationBar with a search bar and large title, how do you style the bottom of the navigation bar to have rounded corners?

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true              
    search.searchBar.delegate = self
            search.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
            self.definesPresentationContext = true
            search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
            self.navigationItem.searchController = search
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe it will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620703/11471446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I found that this works, however, now my search bar text is black on purple vs white? - And I had to set the background color of the view to my purple color and then place a white background view on top of the view.  Thoughts?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
    
    let app = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    app.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    app.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    app.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.30, green: 0.07, blue: 0.63, alpha: 1.00)
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = app
    
     self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isOpaque = true
    search.searchBar.delegate = self
    UISearchBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
    search.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .white
    search.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    search.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    search.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    search.searchBar.placeholder = "Search here"
    self.navigationItem.searchController = search
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Customizing Navigation Bar is some what difficult. But there is an easy way to achieve it using background image. You can set Image to the navigation bar.

Question is already asked by someone else in the stackoverflow so, refer that answer.

Visit:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620703/12775090

Comment: So I understand that code, however, I don't want to disable the navigation bar functionality.  From what I'm reading this hides the navigation bar and places this view over top of it.